# Is it possible to have a popup div that 'breaks out' of an overflow:scroll or overflow:auto container?

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable area that contains popup menus. Conceptually, something like this:

```
<div style="overflow:auto; width:100px; height:100px">
  ... content here that's big enough to trigger scrollbars...
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:$('#popup').show()">Click here</a>
    <div style="position:relative">
      <div id="popup"
           style="display:none; position:absolute; width:150px; height:150px">
        ... more content. This div gets shown and hidden by jquery on click events.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the popup menu pops up, it is also contained within the scrolling div, and doesn't show up outside the 100x100 pixel scrollable area no matter how high I make the z-index. I realize of course that in a sense that's exactly what I asked for when I told the outer div to be overflow:auto in the first place. But for my use case it isn't what I want - I want the popup menu to be "over the top" and able to extend outside the scrollable area, while still staying in the right place, which is to say, directly underneath the "Click here" link. Even though the "Click here" link can move around as the container is scrolled.

I also realize that there are some complicated workarounds I could employ, like putting the popup entirely outside the scrollable div and using javascript to position it. And then I'd need to react to scroll events to reposition it as the content is scrolled, etc. Quite apart from needing to write lots of code to re-implement what the "position:relative/position:absolute" gave me for free, that'd also require quite a bit of refactoring of my own code, so I'd rather avoid it.

I'm wondering if there's some simple trick I can apply to my inner div to tell it to disregard its container's "overflow" property, or, failing that, a handy jquery script that will implement the complicated stuff for me behind the scenes so I just need to call it to get the effect I'm after.

Comment: when you say "popup" you mean a real pop up? like in IE that opens a new window, or your popup is just a div floating in front your page?

Comment: Just the <div id="popup">. I edited the post to clarify slightly how the popup gets shown.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd say that it's not possible to do that without using JS to calculate the position of the link and then display the popup with a position:fixed..

The problem is that your popup is inside a div with `overflow:auto` and everything inside that div will affect the scroll, so to show the popup you'll need to take it outside that div, and the only way i know to do that is by using the position:fixed... (or maybe using position:absolute on the popup, and a wrapper div with position:relative that contains the text and the popups)

so i'll propose 3 solutions:

1. put the popup outside the div with scroll, and when the user clicks
   on the link, display the popup
2. calculate the exact position of the link (x,y) and display the popup using position:fixed and the coordinates
3. use a nice and always-easy-to-use "message box" (e.g. http://csscody.com/demo/wp-content/demo/popup/demo.htm) I know that this is not exactly what you wanted, but.. i ran out of ideas =D

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help! It looks like I will probably end up stuck with positioning it by hand in the end. It's good to know that I can do this with absolute or fixed, though - at least that means I don't need to restructure my entire html and css.

If I find any other way to do it I will; otherwise I'll mark this as 'the answer' - it's just not possible.

Comment: The 3rd solution link is invalid

Answer (score 10):

Displaying a popup inside a of a div with "overflow: auto", "overflow: scroll" or "overflow: hidden" will always generate this kind of issues. By rule, an element child can't be displayed beyond the parent's borders in all these cases because the overflow property makes precisely that. Using "**position: fixed**" to the popup will solve your issue BUT if you scroll down you'll see how the popup is displayed in the old position, previous to the scroll event. To solve this you can use JQuery, as follows:

```
$(".your-popup-PARENT-class").live( {
    mouseenter: function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var position = $(this).offset();
        $(this).find(".your-popup-class").css("top", (position.top + 30) );
        $(this).find(".your-popup-class").css("left", position.left);
        $(this).find(".your-popup-class").css("display", "inherit");
    },
    mouseleave: function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find(".your-popup-class").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

This code segment finds your popup parent element on the DOM tree, saves the current position and display the popup in the same position of the parent. As you can see, you can add or remove needed pixels, (bold code in previous CSS top definition).

Hopefully, this will be hepful for someone else with this kind of issue.

Kind regards!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this approach is helping me, but I am still finding that I need to set the parent to `relative` and the child to `fixed` for the desired effect (and then when I scroll, as predicted, the child element is 'fixed' and doesn't move).  In your example above, what are the position values of parent class and child class?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the effect you're going for is, but if you remove the popup's container, then the popup will show up outside of the scrollable div.

```
<div style="overflow:auto; width:100px; height:100px">
  ... content here that's big enough to trigger scrollbars...
    <div id="popup"
         style="display:none; position:absolute; width:150px; height:150px">
      ... more content. This div gets shown and hidden by jquery on click events.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately I need the "position:relative" because that's what allows the menu to show up in the right place relative to the thing you clicked on to trigger it. Something like:
<div>
  <a href="javascript:$('#popup').show()">Click here</a>
  <div style="position:relative">
    <div id="popup" ...>popup contents</div>
  </div>
</div>
That makes the popup show up directly underneath the "Click here" text, which is what I'm after. I'll edit the original post to clarify that.

Comment: If you don't have any `left` or `top`, then the popup will sit exactly where it was. If that doesn't work out for you, you might just be out of luck.

Comment: left: 0px and top: 0px are implied so I didn't state them. They compute relative to the nearest containing thing with position:relative - which is why that div is necessary.