# Handling negative-position images with overflow:auto

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

Consider the following markup: http://jsfiddle.net/gbWgH/.  Because the list overflows its container and overlaps with the text below, I'd like it to be scrollable instead, so I set it to `overflow:auto`.  However, this cuts off parts of the image: http://jsfiddle.net/gbWgH/1/.  Removing this rule make the image appear properly.

How can I make the text scrollable without cutting off the image?  Is the simplest option to just calculate the coordinates manually using Javascript, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3551909/1397061)?

Comment: Does making the image a CSS background work for you?

Comment: @Diodeus No, it needs to be in a particular position relative to a line of text.

Comment: CSS backgrounds can do that.

Comment: That could work too, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just resorting to Javascript.  Here, an image is positioned 50 pixels to the left and 40 pixels above a `li` with id `"myli"`, inside a `ul` with id `"myul"`, by calculating an offset from the `li`'s absolute position within the page body.  Note that you have to account for the amount the `ul` has been scrolled.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = ...

var li = document.getElementById("myli");
var scrollTop = document.getElementById("myul").scrollTop;

img.style.left = li.offsetLeft - 50 + 'px';
img.style.top = li.offsetTop - 40 - scrollTop + 'px';
img.style.position = 'absolute';

document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

`img {position:relative; top : 20px; left : 20px;}`

Comment: That changes the position of the image, which does not help if, as in my case, the image needs to be in a specific position relative to the text.  In any case, if I wanted to change the position of the image, I could have just changed the container's relative position.