# How to allow scrolling with overflow visible

Tags: css, css-grid

I've got a grid with many elements, having 3 per row. The idea is that you can scroll through them all till you reach the last element. For that I simply add `overflow-y: scroll`

At the same time, I've got an onhover effect which scales the hovered element by 1.01. As I've set `overflow-y: scroll` it cuts off the scaled element.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9a5j173x/23/

Notice the shadow is also cut, I'd like for that to be fully visible too.

```css
.gridParent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #abdbe3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 6px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #063970;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 2px 4px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-duration: 150ms;
}

.child:hover {
  scale: 1.05;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridParent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you can afford to just use a padding on gridParent that should give you enough buffer room to see the scaling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to have some `padding` you could use this solution

The trick is to have in `.gridParent` some `padding` to "allow content growth" and then use `background-clip: content-box, padding-box;` to not have colored background on the "padding pixels"

The `padding` though should be adjusted to your specific sizes, you could play around, `10px` works great for fiddle and code snippet below, in real life you might want to calculate it more precisely.

If you are not allowed to have additional `padding`, then most likely you would need to go to javascript, you check out discussions here - [Is it possible to have a popup div that 'breaks out' of an overflow:scroll or overflow:auto container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550795/is-it-possible-to-have-a-popup-div-that-breaks-out-of-an-overflowscroll-or-ov)

```css
.gridParent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #abdbe3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 6px;
    padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-clip: content-box, padding-box;
}

.child {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #063970;
  color: white;
  
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 2px 4px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
  
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-duration: 150ms;
}

.child:hover {
  scale: 1.05;
}
```

```html
  <div class="gridParent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, with padding it works. I can't really add padding, unfortunately, but I might be able to hack it in with negative margin, etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add `padding-bottom` with a small value to the parent grid container and that works. I've also used the `transform-origin` with `:child` selectors so that the left and right elements don't get clipped and the top row moves down.

```css
.gridParent {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #abdbe3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  gap: 6px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.child {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #063970;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 2px 4px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-duration: 150ms;
}

.child:hover {
  scale: 1.05;
}

.child:nth-child(3n+1) {
  transform-origin: left;
}

.child:nth-child(3n+3) {
  transform-origin: right;
}

.child:first-child {
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  transform-origin: top;
}

.child:nth-child(3) {
  transform-origin: top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridParent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I might have explained the issue badly, but with your solution we've got the same problem. The scaled element gets cropped from all sides, not just the bottom. I'm trying to make it so when it scales, the parent grid doesn't crop the hovered element

Comment: I think I understand now. Use transform-origin to control which way the elements scale. I've added the left and right ones using nth-child() rules.